# How to support .Net MAUI Splash screen in both portrait and landscape with full screen SVG resource

Tags: maui

I need to create splash screen with full screen image supporting both portrait and lanscape mode in .Net MAUI common place for Android and iOS. There is a document in dotnet maui https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/splashscreen?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android this explains with limited option that is for portrait mode only. Any examples or document how we can support both the orienation using single SVG file which will be having images internally.
I have gonethrough below examples related to svg:
[SVG mobile orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642266/svg-mobile-orientation-change).
[Switch X and Y axis for everything in SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69213683/switch-x-and-y-axis-for-everything-in-svg).
Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create the .xml file on the Android platform to set the Landscape Mode.

You can check this [Landscape Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/splash-screen#landscape-mode) for more information.

Comment: that is by using xamarin native approach. I want this to implement using .net MAUI in common resource for both android and iOS.

Comment: Yes, it uses the xamarin native approach. But in the maui it does not have the way to set the common resource for the android and iOS, you need to set the splashscreen in landscape for both different platforms.